# Sass how to use ampersand within :not() pseudo class to mean not having a parent class?

Tags: css, sass, parent, pseudo-class, ampersand

I need add a condition "not parent class" to the code but it is not working.

Below is what I've tried:

```
.display-download-icon {
  &:not(.media-2 &){ // if it does not has a parent with .media-2 class
    &:hover {
      .image-overlay {
        display: block;
        opacity: 1;
        z-index: 2;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But it translates into the CSS below:

```
.display-download-icon:not(.media-2 .display-download-icon):hover .image-overlay {
  display: block;
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

The HTML structure is:

```
<div class="media-2">
  <div class="display-download-icon">
    <div class="image-overlay"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Can you help?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

To begin with, we have to get some things straight. You probably misunderstood [this article](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/style-rules/parent-selector) with the somewhat unfortunate title. Although CSS has a child selector, it lacks the possibility to select parents. As SASS is only a more convenient way to write CSS, SASS cannot have such a thing either. This said, let's move on to your question.

If I understand you correctly, you want to have the hover effect on the `image-overlay` element only if it is not contained in an element with the class `media-2`.
If that's the case, then you will have to change your approach.

First, define the normal behaviour, *i.e* the one that is expected for all the elements except the ones with the `.media-2` class. Then define a new rule for the `.media-2` class children.

#### SASS

```css
.display-download-icon {
  display: block; /* Just for the demo */
  height: 100px; /* Just for the demo */
  width: 100%; /* Just for the demo */
  border: 1px solid black; /* Just for the demo */
  margin-bottom: 10px; /* Just for the demo */

  > .image-overlay {
    display: block;
    opacity: 1;
    z-index: 2;
  
    height: 100%; /* Just for the demo */
    width: 100%; /* Just for the demo */

    &:hover {
      background: red; /* Just for the demo */
    }
  }
}

.media-2 .display-download-icon > .image-overlay:hover {
  background: none; /* Just for the demo */
}
```

#### Snippet

Check this snippet for the functionality

```css
.display-download-icon {
  display: block;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.display-download-icon > .image-overlay {
  display: block;
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 2;
  
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.display-download-icon > .image-overlay:hover {
  background: red;
}

.media-2 .display-download-icon > .image-overlay:hover {
  background: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="media-1">
  <div class="display-download-icon">
    <div class="image-overlay"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="media-2">
  <div class="display-download-icon">
    <div class="image-overlay"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="media-3">
  <div class="display-download-icon">
    <div class="image-overlay"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I hope that you get the idea.

Comment: Thank you! This is it.

Comment: @FelipeToledo Happy to help. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

All the `"&"` does is act as an alias for the preceding parent selector, which is why you are getting the compiled output you are (because of the "&" after the .media-2 classname) . You just need to remove the last "&" and it will compile fine.

```
.display-download-icon {
  &:not(.media-2){ // removed the "&"
    &:hover {
      .image-overlay {
        display: block;
        opacity: 1;
        z-index: 2;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The above with compile to
.display-download-icon:not(.media-2):hover .image-overlay {
display: block;
opacity: 1;
z-index: 2;
}

But you can also remove some of that nesting as well to make it more readable

```
.display-download-icon:not(.media-2):hover {
  .image-overlay {
     display: block;
     opacity: 1;
     z-index: 2;
   }
}
```

Which will compile to the same output.

Comment: That does not solves it. The HTML structure is <div class="media-2"><div class="display-download-icon"><div class="image-overlay"></div></div></div>

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, there's no such thing as a parent selector in CSS, so this isn't really a Sass ampersand issue as much as a core behaviour of CSS.

You'll need to write a dedicated rule like this:

```css
/* base icon styling */
.display-download-icon {
  ...
}

/* separate rule for parent case */
div:not(.media-2) {
  .display-download-icon {
    &:hover {
      .image-overlay {
        display: block;
        opacity: 1;
        z-index: 2;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Parent selector as ampersand exists in SASS. Like .child { .parent & { } } that translates into .parent .child